# Javascript Modal Windows Libraries

Tags: html, javascript

I am looking for a simple Modal Window Lib in JS.

What I require from it, is to be able to 
. load a url response into the modal
. load text in to the modal

What are the options I have ?

Note: I am using jQuery. Therefore, I can use a jQuery Modal plugin as well.

Thanks,
Prakash Raman

Answer (score 1):

Check out Jquery UI's [Modal Window](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/).

Comment: thanks, but I was looking for a more, "LightBox" kind of an option.

Comment: @Prakash Raman: Sure, it has that option too. Go to this link and click on "Create new user" button: http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/#modal-form . You can customize the CSS to make it look more darker too. This modal window has a looootttt of customization available.

Comment: @Prakash Raman: And you can use JQuery to post an ajax request to the server and load a url response into that box.